# Where does au-fugiō come from?

Tags: etymology, preposition, prefix

Hittite has a verbal prefix *u-* that indicates motion away from something. Kloekhorst connects it to Latin *au-fugiō*, "to flee from", saying they both come from PIE **h₂-u-*.

However, I'd always thought *au-* in Latin was just the form of *ab-* before *f* (cf *au-ferō*).

Is Kloekhorst right (or, rather, are his views commonly accepted) about this? And how much evidence is there either way?

Comment: Some discussion here, and an answer by Alex B quoting de Vaan: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/why-does-b-differ-between-l-offero-and-l-aufero

Comment: compare German *abhauen* "to leave, get away" (usually quickly so). the apparent stem *hauen* "to hew" (beat, strike) makes close to no sense here. To split off, branch off and similar might make sense somehow, but I suggest rebracketing, in which case it might be relevant. Also see *die Biege machen* (idem); *abbiegen* ("to turn" in the sense "make a left", but wiktionary has more; trivially *biegen* "bend", cp "get bent"). \*Hu implies \*Hew, cp. \*kewp "bend" (IIRC), perhaps \*kaput (cp "to head of"), or the same element as in *away* (I want to say the same as in L *e-x*), or *ever*.

Comment: also see https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/abuhaz supposing \*Hepo, trivially

Comment: @vectory You seem to be talking about descendants of *_h₂(e)po-_, cognate with Latin _ab_; I'm asking about Kloekhorst's view that Latin _au-fugiō_ comes instead from *_h₂-u-_.

Comment: Kind of. It's the most obvious assumption, isn't it? But if I suppose rebracketing in abhauen (and geminated h out of the bue), then *-a*  is left to be explained. I could even imagine another comparison, *abhängen* (to get away from, leave behind, literally *hang off*) that might show n-infix (?) and original velar; just for sake of the argument. Eitherway, an internal derivation of \*h2(e)po is wanted, yes. Its stem might be the stem in au-fugio, contracted with *fui* and then some.

Comment: Cyril Bosch with *Untersuchungen zur hethitischen Raumgrammatik* treats *u-* in sections 2.2.2.1 and 4.1.2. The former is not previewed in google books, the latter, on p. [342](https://books.google.de/books?id=RNPmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA419&dq=lexikon+der+indogermanischen+partikeln+Dunkel&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAt8vKpODmAhWz6KYKHUXjAHwQuwUINzAC#v=onepage&q=lexikon%20der%20indogermanischen%20partikeln%20Dunkel&f=false), is not clear to me, paraphrased: *it was a topologic term, gained reference to the "Centrum deicticum" through pragmatism, later "inferierte Perspektive" and loss of prior function*

Comment: [cont.] *If 'her' ~ ablative/adjective 'von … weg' then 'hin' ~ terminative 'an/auf … hin', cp. Gr.* epi *'an/auf', etc. in line with Kloekhorst (2008: 661) instead of Gr.* apo *'von/weg', Slav.* po, *etc. thus \*poi, cp. TochA* -pi *[w.R.]. The diphtong is secured by the* a *in* payi-/pai-[zi] *(against Melchert 1994 \*pe), which may be "univerbiert" after \*h1 elided, but before monophtongization of [\*oiH] (\*poi-antsi, panzi versus \*h2uh1ienti, huyanti)*

Comment: I know some of these words. The paragraph is introduced by a broad reconstruction for *pe*: *\*(H)PVi- or \*(H)Pe(h1)-; to which* u- *should be compared on semantic grounds*. Anyhow, another interesting bit might be p. 317 *uwa-*, *sometimes though implying immediacy [with references]*